# Access product sku within app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount

Tags: magento2, php, sku

Is there a way to get the product sku within the app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount.phtml file?

I need to retrieve the product sku value there, because i want to insert it to

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
content_type: 'product',
content_ids: /* sku value here */
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get the sku of current product

```
$_product = $block->getProduct()
$productsku = $_product->getSku()
```

Or u can use object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product') 
$productsku = $product->getSku();
```

Comment: When using the object manager my homepage breaks up.
but with the first approach you suggested it works.
I found myself the solution too.
The other approach on solving this is to change block and add the following code in details.phtml
<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getSku(); ?>
But thank you for your answer i will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

This should return current product:
`$this->_registry->registry('current_product')`, so using
`$this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getSku()` will return sku of current product.
I recommend to use call it in function in Block.

Comment: this breaks my homepage appearance.

Comment: oh right. Do you need it on product page or everywhere price is showed?

Comment: I just edited the question. I want to access the sku product value in that file because i need to added to the facebook pixel content_id.